# Newsletter plugin for WordPress preview not working with Elementor editor

Tags: newsletter

I'm trying to use [Newsletter plugin for WordPress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/newsletter/) but it doesn't show preview without that it is hard to changes.

[image]

For now I need to click "Update" button and see the changes and again come back to edit mode and re-do changes.

Please let me know how to fix this ?

I'm referring to [this YT video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uoXsxRymGS4&ab_channel=ICDSoft)

Comment: You'll probably have to ask the plugin authors for help, or Elementor. I don't know either of the plugins.